# Outlook 2013 background bump

Tags: outlook, html-email

[image]

I'm experiencing an issue with Outlook 2013 (and 2007). The image shows the issue. Providing partial HTML below.

I've tested in Litmus as well and this is only showing up in 2013/2007. I can't seem to isolate what the issue could be and I'm hoping a 2nd pair of eyes will help.

```
<td width="270" style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; font-size: 14px; line-height: 19px; padding: 0;" align="left" valign="top">
                  <table width="100%" style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;">
                    <tr style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;" align="left">
                      <td style="color: #ffffff; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; font-size: 14px; line-height: 19px; padding: 0;" align="left" valign="top">
                        <table style="width: 100%; border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;">
                          <tr style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;" align="left">
                            <td style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; font-size: 14px; line-height: 19px; padding: 0;" align="left" valign="top">
                              <img src="table-topper.jpg" alt="" width="270" height="20" style="display: block; outline: 0;">
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;" align="left">
                            <td width="100%" style="background-color:#5b8f20;vertical-align: top; text-align: left; font-size: 14px; line-height: 19px; padding: 0 20px;width:230px;" align="left" valign="top">
                              <h2 style="text-align: center; font-size: 33px; font-weight: normal; text-transform: uppercase; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;color: #ffffff;padding-bottom: 20px; border-bottom-width: 2px; border-bottom-color: #ffffff; border-bottom-style: solid; margin: 0 0 15px;" align="center" class="h2">Dragons VIP</h2>
                              <p style="border-bottom-color: #ffffff; border-bottom-width: 2px; border-bottom-style: solid; font-size: 16px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-align: left; line-height: 22px; margin: 0 0 10px; padding: 0 0 20px; color:#ffffff;" align="left">
                                <strong>
                                  Thursday, August 20, 2015
                                  <br> 11:30am–1:00pm
                                  <br> Fifth Third Field
                                </strong>
                              </p>
                              <p style="color:#ffffff;font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-align: left; line-height: 22px; margin: 0 0 10px; padding: 0;" align="left">Space is limited, so don't delay. To RSVP, compliments of Fifth Third Bank, please contact Colleen Santella with the Dayton Dragons by August 13th.</p>

                              <p style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-align: left; line-height: 22px; margin: 0 0 10px; padding: 0;" align="left">
                                <a href="mailto:xxx.xxx@xxx.com">
                                  <img src="rsvp-btn.png" alt="" width="230" height="52" style="display: block; outline: 0;">
                                </a>
                              </p>

                              <p style="color:#ffffff;font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-align: left; line-height: 22px; margin: 0 0 10px; padding: 0;" align="left"><a href="mailto:colleen.santella@daytondragons.com" target="_blank" style="color: #ffffff; display: inline-block; width: 230px;">xxx.xxx@daytondragons.com</a> or at (xxx) xxx-xxxx x 112</p>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;" align="left">
                            <td style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; font-size: 14px; line-height: 19px; padding: 0;" align="left" valign="top">
                              <img src="table-bot.jpg" alt="" width="270" height="20" style="display: block; outline: 0;">
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>

                </td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed / added TD widths to fix this issue.

Comment: Please expand your answer to include the before and after of the code. It is not possible with a quick glance to tell what you did to solve it. ALSO if that is your final solution, please mark this answer as accepted, to mark the question as "answered" in search results